# Can't get simulators in the IOS devices list in XCode

Tags: xcode

OSX Mountain Lion (10.8.2)
XCode 4.4.1

Cannot get the list of IOS Devices in the XCode ( top left list ). As i remember it's some sort of SDK selection problem. Somewhere, in the project properties. But cannot figure out, in the new OSX and XCode installation. Help pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ios devices available depend on at least a couple of things

- your project/ target device settings
  check your project (info) and target (summary) "deployment target" settings.
- what simulators you have installed
  in preferences > downloads you can pick up simulators you may need.

For example, if your project deployment target is ios6 but you don't have the iOS6 simulator installed, or an iOS6 device attached, no options will appear in the list.

You should also upgrade to Xcode 4.5.2. I don't think iOS6 is included in 4.4.1